# Dynamically create Ruby variables with string interpolation

Tags: ruby, variables, interpolation

I want to do something like:

```
4.times do |n|
  "member#{n}" = Fabricate(:user)
end
```

Calling `member1`, `member2` etc.. would give me user instances. Is #send or #eval useful to my situation? Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot dynamically set `local variables` in this manner because what you are actually trying to do is set a `String`. Your code is interpreted as follows

```
"member1" = Fabricate(:user)
```

Which will raise a `SyntaxError` for unexpected `=` because you cannot set a `String` to anything.

You can however perform this operation with `instance_variables` like so:

```
4.times do |n|
  instance_variable_set("@member#{n}", Fabricate(:user))
end
```

Then access them with `@member1`,`@member2`, etc.

To answer your second question is no `send` and `eval` have no particular use in this case